# Why background image is not visible using background property in css

Tags: html, css

I am using Pug and My image is not visible. I am not getting why so.

I have also  flutter image there in the folder.

One more help I wanted the image to be fitted in the box exactly as the height and width of given list, I used 'object-fit:cover' but that doesn't work for me. Here below is example of want i wanted[image]

```css
#list1{
    list-style: none;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: url('https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*yvz6FsBEh-JGN_miQIMEXA.jpeg');
}
```

```html
<section class="Skill_Section">
    <ul class="Cards">
        <li id="list1"></li>
        <li id="list2"></li>
        <li id="list3"></li>
        <li id="list4"></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: you also have to set a width since you don't have any content

Comment: Please include a snippet in your question which we can run to see the problem see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth ..Actually, my code is working fine when I use an online URL for Image but if I include an image from my pc files then it is not loading on the server, as I am using localhost to launch my website instead if I use Live server then the image load successfully

Comment: @AhmedMasud.. Actually, my code is working fine when I use an online URL for Image but if I include an image from my pc files then it is not loading on the server, as I am using localhost to launch my website instead if I use a Live server then the image load successfully

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your image Path, then use the same height-width image what is your div height-width, And add these CSS **background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;**

Answer (score 0):

first set the width and height to all li's and then checkout

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your problem, you need to do like below.
[image]

If that so, This is the code for it.

**HTML**

```
<section class="Skill_Section">
    <ul class="Cards">
        <li id="list1">This is the text one.</li>
        <li id="list2">This is the text two.</li>
        <li id="list3">This is the text three.</li>
        <li id="list4">This is the text three.</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  display: flex;

}

li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .40), rgba(0, 0, 0, .40)),url("https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*yvz6FsBEh-JGN_miQIMEXA.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  color: #F90716;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: Actually, my code is working fine when I use an online URL for Image but if I include an image from my pc files then it is not loading on the server, as I am using localhost to launch my website instead if I use Live server  then the image load successfully

Comment: did you give the correct path?

Comment: yes I gave the correct path as I said that if I launch the same code using vs code extension Live server then it loads perfectly but when I try using localhost server then it shows a blank